# Evaluate condition from value file in Helm template

Tags: kubernetes-helm, sprig-template-functions

When I have a line in my values.yaml file:

```
condition: "eq .Release.Namespace dev"
```

Can I evaluate this in the template somehow?

```
{{- if .condition  }}
status: "development"
{{- end }}
```

I've tried to do the above but that is not working, is there something else I can do to achieve this?

Comment: `values.yaml` should contain **values**, not logic.

Answer (score 3):

A better practice would be to have a Helm values file that explicitly stated these sorts of conditions, even if they're redundant.

```yaml
# values.dev.yaml
status: development
```

```yaml
# configmap.yaml
status: {{ .Values.status }}
```

```sh
helm install release-name . -f values.dev.yaml -n dev
```

---

This is technically possible, though.  One of Helm's extension functions (not part of the core Go text/template library or Sprig) is [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function), which allows you to evaluate an arbitrary string as though it were a template string.  You'd need to wrap that value in `{{ ... }}` to force it to be evaluated as an expression.  But, this does work, and `helm template` outputs the correct values:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: demo
data:
  {{/* This is the raw condition string from values.yaml */}}
  condition: {{ .Values.condition }}

  {{/* This calls `tpl` on that string, and dumps out the result */}}
  evaluated: {{ tpl (printf "{{%s}}" .Values.condition) . }}

  {{/* `tpl` produces a string out, but you can compare it */}}
{{- if eq "true" (tpl (printf "{{%s}}" .Values.condition) .) }}
  status: development
{{- else }}
  status: production
{{- end }}
```

My experience with Helm templating is that it's *possible* to do some pretty complicated things in a template, but once you get up to writing serious code and dynamic evaluation there, you start to get into normal software lifecycle problems, and for example it's hard to unit-test this setup.